# process.env variable returns undefined from a specific file

Tags: node.js, express

I have got a configuration file called `dev.js` which contains an object that has a key called `dbURL` which holds database url for MongoDB. It looks like this exactly.

```
export const config = {
    dbURL: 'mongodb+srv://...'
}
```

And I have got another file called `db.js` where I import the above `dev.js` file and use the `dbURL` key in order to connect to the database.

```
import { connect as _connect } from 'mongoose';
import {config} from '../config/dev';

const connect = (url = config.dbURL, opts = {}) => {
    return _connect(
        url,
        {}, err => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Connected to MongoDB!')
        }
    )
}
export default connect;
```

The problem is if I tried to change the `dbURL`'s value in the `dev.js` file to be `process.env.DEV_DB` for example.

```
export const config = {
    dbURL: process.env.DEV_DB
}
```

The `.env` file looks like this

```
DEV_DB = "mongodb+srv://...."
```

It actually returns `undefined`, although I tried to `console.log(process.env.DEV_DB)` in the `db.js` file and it printed the database url normally.

```
import { connect as _connect } from 'mongoose';
import {config} from '../config/dev';

const connect = (url = config.dbURL, opts = {}) => {
    console.log(config) //logs {dbURL: undefined}
    console.log(process.env.DEV_DB) //logs the database url normally
    return _connect(
        url,
        {}, err => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Connected to MongoDB!')
        }
    )
}
export default connect;
```

When I tried to log the `process.env.DEV_DB` in the `dev.js` file, it logged `undefined` as well.

Note: The `dotenv` is imported at the top of the application, and the `.env` is in the root file.

Comment: iirc (sorry, I'm a bit rusty!) process.env only shows up in files that are "run". When you import `config = {}...` from `dev.js` it doesn't actually run the file, only include it. Converting config to a function that returns an object might work, but if it doesn't, try importing `require('dotenv').config()` at the top of dev.js

Comment: @PeiQiTea I tried importing it, and it worked! I get it now how `process.env` shows up. Thank you so much <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you imported dotenv at the top of your dev.js file as well? That solved it for me when I tried it locally.

Comment: I tried it right now, and it worked! but I don't actually get what happened?

Comment: Glad to hear! dotenv.config() requires initialization within every file where you wish to access environment variables. Or did it work without it (?)

Comment: It worked when I added `require("dotenv").config()` at the top of `dev.js`

Answer (score 0):

For my case, despite adding `require("dotenv").config();` at the top of the file, instead I fixed it by adding the path to the .env file like this

`require("dotenv").config({ path:"add/path/to your/.env file"});`